# Angular2: ngDestroy called for component which is ngFor-ed and its reference has changed

Tags: angular

I have a small example app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j64h3n). 
Several objects (`this.entries in app.component`) are *ngFor-ed and used as input properties for a custom component (`test.component.ts`). When you click the button next to each component its input property is changed to a new object - first the index in the array is retrieved and then the item for that index is set to a new copy (I use such logic because I'm using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in my other app). When this happens, `ngDestroy` is called and the component is reinitialized (actually a new component is created).

I already tried `trackBy`, but nothing changes.

Why is this behaviour and how can I avoid that? What I need is just to use `ngOnChanges` and not have a whole new component created.
While the example here is really simple, I have other situations when similar logic for changing input properties is run more frequently.

Comment: To me it looks like you have forgotten to implement the interfaces on the class, like:

export class TestComponent implements OnChanges, OnDestroy  {

Comment: This shouldn't change the situation, they are always called in the resulting JavaScript. The point is that the component is recreated upon changing its input property instead of just calling ngOnChanges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have fixed your example with just trackBy function. perhaps you were doing it wrong.
see
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vk4mh2?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: What if you change the id? basically fully replace the object in question?

Comment: it seems that tracking by index will serve you right in this case

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know that the second parameter is the item itself. So I had written a single parameter function and obviously item.id returned undefined. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I put some thought into this. The TrackBy might work in a very specific situation, but I think quite often it wont. If the id changes, you'd get a ngOnDestory and if another field changes, I think the view would ignore it.

I can't think of an elegant solution, but here's a workable one:

HTML:

```
<test-comp *ngFor="let t of entiresRecords" [prop]="entries[t]" (buttonClick)="onButtonClicked($event)"></test-comp>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent  {
  entiresRecords;

  entries = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.entiresRecords = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.entries.length; i++) {
      this.entiresRecords.push(i);
    }
  }

  onButtonClicked (id: number) {
     const targetIndex = this.entries.findIndex(t => t.id === id);
     const copy = Object.assign({}, this.entries[targetIndex], {id: this.entries[targetIndex].id + 3});
     this.entries[targetIndex] = copy;
  }
}
```

Basically what I've done is created a separate array, for the sole purpose of maintaining the existance of the temp-comp in the dom. This array wouldn't change. I mean, you could write some functionality to add/remove elements if your situation required, but if you are simply reusing the same number of nodes, it wouldn't be necessary to change it.

Now you are free to manipulate the entries array as you please (as long as you maintain the same number of elements)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, actually trackBy worked, I just missed the index parameter and that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: Awesome, glad that worked for you :P Its a cleaner answer for sure